# Why use SurfaceView or TextureView for custom drawing? Their Canvas isn't hardware accelerated

Tags: android, animation, canvas, surfaceview, textureview

So I'm doing a number of Canvas drawText, drawPath, drawArc, drawLine, and drawCircle for an animation...

Using SurfaceView, doing lockCanvas & unlockCanvasAndPost, eventually discover that drawing to the canvas is taking > 16ms say 1 in 20 times

Hardware draw times? 0-2 milliseconds

So why does Lunar Lander <3 SurfaceView? I don't think I could ever beat a hardware accelerated canvas vs a software decelerated canvas.

Comment: First, Lunar Lander was written in 2008 or so, IIRC. Second, `TextureView` is hardware accelerated, AFAIK -- it's certainly requires a hardware-accelerated window. Third, use Traceview to determine precisely where you are taking your time, and check your logs to see if your "1 in 20 times" is due to garbage collection that you may need to aim to avoid (e.g., object pooling).

Comment: If you want to see what's going on in context with the system compositor, and your device supports it, use systrace to do your profiling (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html).  Make sure you understand http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html .  FWIW, I'd recommend Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/) over Lunar Lander as sample code, but not everyone wants to get into OpenGL ES.

Comment: @CommonsWare TextureView's Canvas is not hardware accelerated.

Comment: @fadden Do you think I need to just give it up on Android animation @ go to openGL? Do most simple games or good animations use openGL instead of Android tween animation APIs or refreshing on a schedule? I'm starting to feel that way.

Comment: I don't have a good sense for what most simple games do.  I expect a lot of them use Canvas because it's simply more convenient (e.g. you have everything you need to draw text).  GLES is much more flexible and you can control everything that goes on... but that's another way of saying that it's more complicated and you have to control everything that goes on.  The best approach is probably to use a simple open-source GLES-based 2D game engine, but a lot of people want the experience of writing the engine-type code themselves.

Comment: @McNinja - the docs say "TextureView can only be used in a hardware accelerated window. When rendered in software, TextureView will draw nothing." at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html